# Custom logic for exposed filters in a Drupal view

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'm working on a Drupal site and would love some advice on this. Currently, a user enters his level for a number of different skills. This is stored in a CCK integer field and exposed to the user as a drop-down widget containing the key/value pairs 1|Beginner, 2|Intermediate, 3|Advanced.

In a view, I expose the allowed values for each skill, which are presented to the user as checkboxes (using the Better Exposed Filters module) and then listed in a sortable table. In practice, users generally search for people who have "at least knowledge level X in skill Y". Is there a module or straightforward way to display the allowed values as a drop-down and use a "greater than" operator in the query instead of a "one of"?

Any sample code or advice on how to dynamically change the filter logic or the WHERE clause of the query would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [hook_views_query_alter()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/function/hook_views_query_alter/6), while I haven't specifically altered the WHERE clause, I have altered the SORTBY clause and the idea behind both should be relatively similar.

Here's a quick piece of code:

```
function my_module_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  switch ($view->name) {
    case 'view1':
      $args = _my_module_get_querystring();
      switch ($args['condition']) {
        case 'condition1':
          $query->where[0]['args'][0] = 1;
          break;

        case 'condition2':
          $query->where[0]['args'][0] = 2;
          break;
      }
      break;
  }
}

/**
 * Returns querystring as an array.
 */
function _my_module_get_querystring() {
  $string = drupal_query_string_encode($_REQUEST, array_merge(array('q'), array_keys($_COOKIE)));
  $args = explode('&', $string);
  foreach ($args as $id => $string) {
    unset($args[$id]);
    $string = explode('=', $string);
    $args[$string[0]] = str_replace(' ', '-', $string[1]);
  }
  return $args;
}
```

This particular piece would allow you to alter the WHERE clause using a querystring (?condition=condition1), but you could alter it to get the arguments however you wish.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think my brain just exploded...but thanks for the code sample! I guess it's time to do some reading up on module development and view hooks to understand what some of these bits mean. Any recommended tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

Using Decipher's sample and spending a few hours reading up and playing around, I've gotten a basic module that works perfectly for my needs.  Thanks again!

Here's my code if anyone else comes across a similar need:

```
<?php
// $Id$
/**
* @file
* Module for modifying the views query to change an EQUALS 
* to a GREATER THAN for specific filters.
*/


function views_greater_than_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {

//only implement for views that have Search in their name
    if(strstr($view->name, "search")) {

        $whereclauses = $query->where[0]['clauses'];

        foreach ($whereclauses as $i=>$currentrow) {

            $currentrow = str_replace('= %d', '>= %d', $currentrow);    
            $query->where[0]['clauses'][$i] = $currentrow;
    }

    unset($whereclauses);
    }
}
```